# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'type' - Python Web Scraping Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, attributes

Currently writing a webscraper to scrape some reviews. The goal is to scrape reviews over multiple URLS. Therefore, i made a list of urls. I want to retrieve the content of the specific reviews per url and merge them in one list.
When i only scrape one page, everything works like a charm. However, when i try to scrape multiple pagines. See the following code plus error:

```
from lxml import html
from urllib import request
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser
import csv
import re

links = open('file')
urls = links.readlines()

for url in urls:
    req=requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(request.urlopen(req).read().decode(encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore"))  
    reviews = tree.xpath('//*[@class="review-body"]')
    reviews = [r.text_content() for r in reviews]
    reviews = [r.replace('\n', ' ') for r in reviews]
    reviews = [r.replace('\r', ' ') for r in reviews]
    reviews = [r.replace('                  ', '') for r in reviews]  

protocol = req.type
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'type'.
```

Can somebody explain to me what this is and how i can solve this?

Comment: Well quite simply: you try to access an attribute `type` that does not exist on the (ill-named) `req` object. The solution is plain obvious: do not try to access this attribute.

Comment: Well indeed, the object doesn't have a `type` attribute. Why do you think it does and what would it be? Why are you trying to access it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. To be honest, i am still in the process of learning Python, scraping, so i cannot give an answer to that. I thought, well if scraping one page works, what could then go wrong with two. But i am clearly missing something as this error comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `reviews` list outside of `for` loop.

This way you will fill it while iterating.

You can either:

1. append temporary list of reviews in each loop step (`temp`) and then you will have `reviews = [ [...], [...]]` or
2. add temporary list with `+` operator e.g. `reviews += temp` which should result in what you probably expect to end up with.

Here is the possible resolution:

```
from lxml import html
from urllib import request
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser
import csv
import re

links = open('file', 'r')

reviews = []

for url in links:
    req = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(req.content.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore"))
    temp = tree.xpath('//*[@class="review-body"]')
    temp = [r.text_content() for r in temp]
    temp = [r.replace('\n', ' ') for r in temp]
    temp = [r.replace('\r', ' ') for r in temp]
    temp = [r.replace('                  ', '') for r in temp]
    reviews += temp
```

3. As for the `AttributeError` it seems you are trying to access attribute that doesn't exist.

Edit 1.

1. `links` is an iterable that can be iterated to fetch line by line. This way you do not have to read all lines in memory.
2. `req` has a `content` and `text` attributes. Both holds page HTML source just depending on encoding.

Comment: "Issue with AttributeError is that you try to access req from out of for loop scope where it is defined. You can't do it" => chapter and verse please ? Of course you can, there's no 'block' scope in Python.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respons Ikac. When i try your suggested code it still gives me the error strangely.